# what does regular, Turing-decidable and Turing-recognisable mean?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, computation-theory, turing-machines, decidable

I know this question has been asked earlier, but I honestly don't understand it clearly.

I'm currently undergoing a study about the theory of computation and I'm coming to the terms "Prove that a language is decidable, recognizable or regular".

In simplest term what do they actually mean, and how do we prove such things?

Comment: I might add that this is a very basic topic of theoretical computer science, that is very well covered on the Internet and in books. You might want to look for a good source (like a book) to help you understand the concepts well. Practising to prove such things is also very helpful in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

We are talking about a language [image: L] over an Alphabet [image: Sigma], which means that [image: L is a subset of Sigma*] ([image: L] consists of words that consist of letters from [image: Sigma]).

**[image: L] being decidable**
means that there exists a Turing machine [image: T], such that [image: T] will *halt and accept* for any input word [image: omega in L] and *halt and reject* for any input word [image: omega not in L].

**[image: L] being recognisable**
means that there exists a Turing machine [image: T], such that [image: T] will *halt and accept* for any input word [image: omega in L] and *halt or not halt* (but not halt and accept!) for any input [image: omega not in L].

see also [Recognizable vs Decidable on MathExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25802/recognizable-vs-decidable) for the difference.

**[image: L] being regular**
means that [image: L] can be created by *regular expressions*. It is important to note that these regular expressions in theoretical computer science are different from the RegEx features known in Programming Languages like PERL or Java. In fact, these RegExes are truly more powerful (don’t known if that’s the correct english term) than regular expressions.

A good definition of regular expressions is given [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~elomaa/teach/iTCS-3.pdf):

For an alphabet [image: Sigma]

- [image: the empty set] and [image: epsilon] (the empty set and the empty word) is a regular expression
- [image: a] for any [image: a in Sigma] (any letter from the alpabet) is a regular expression
- if [image: R1] and [image: R2] are regular expressions, these are regular expressions, too:

  - [image: R1 and R2] (meaning [image: R1] *or* [image: R2])
  - [image: R1 concatenated with R2] (meaning the concatenation of [image: R1] and [image: R2])
  - [image: R1*] (meaning [image: R1], any number of repetitions of [image: R1] or the empty word [image: epsilon])

and nothing else is a regular expression.

### How do we proof something like that?

#### Turing machines

To prove decidability or recognisability, it’s often easiest to provide a Turing machine with the desired attributes. Because of the [Church-Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis), any programming language is as powerful as a Turing machine. So in my courses, it was perfectly acceptable to provide an algorithm in a programming language or pseudo code.

Note that any language that is recognisable is also decidable (but not the other way around).

#### Regular Expressions

To prove regularity, it’s most of the time easiest to just provide a regular expression that constructs the language. Sometimes a prove is needed that the regular expression really constructs exactly [image: L], which is usually not too difficult (often it’s plain obvious).

In many lectures, there is a convention on regular expressions that allows a more intuitive and shorter (but not more powerful) syntax.

It may be interesting to know that regular languages are exactly the languages that can be recognised by [finite automatons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton). Note that any regular language is also decidable (and thus recognisable).

To *disprove* regularity, I’m just going to mention the [pumping lemma for regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages).